# Disable a control inside a gridview

Tags: asp.net

Hi i want to disable link-bottoms control in a grid view with the condition of a special  value . for example if the count for a row become 0 ,the link bottom for that row should be invisible . what should i do? where should i write the code?
here is cod that i write in row command grid view but it works only of i push the link bottom!! but i want to apply this cod to my page before loading.
please guide me

```
    int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    idx = idx - (GridView1.PageSize * GridView1.PageIndex);

    int ID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[idx].Value;
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(ID) FROM ReviwerArticle where ArticleID=@ArticleID", sqlconn);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleID", ID);

    sqlconn.Open();
    int count = ((int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());

    sqlconn.Close();
    if (count == 0)
    {
                ((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FindControl("LinkButton4") as LinkButton).Visible = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then don't try to do it `onrowcommand` as this will only fire when an action is performed. if you are using a function in the codebehind to load your data check at that point how many rows are being pushed to the gridview. if the rows are zero then disable the button. if the rows are greater than 0 enabled the button.

Comment: Thank you for your answering...for this project i used DataSqlSource...so there is no cod behind for this part. i have just a query in DataSqlSource. Is there any way to do that within a DataSqlSource?

Answer (score 0):

Do it inside the RowDataBound event of GridView..

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value;
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(ID) FROM ReviwerArticle where ArticleID=@ArticleID", sqlconn);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArticleID", ID);

    sqlconn.Open();
    int count = ((int)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar());

    sqlconn.Close();
    if (count == 0)
    {
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("LinkButton4") as LinkButton).Visible = false;

    }
        }
```